# error in necessitas while use openCV libs

Tags: android, qt, opencv, qt4

I'm programming in QT for android device and need to use openCV for capture from camera. I already used Qt creator and linked openCV and used camera, but in Qt for android (necessitas) when build program, show this errors:

```
C:/OpenCV2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_highgui.a(cap_images.o): In function `CvCapture_Images::close()':
    cap_images.cpp:(.text._ZN16CvCapture_Images5closeEv+0x1c): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
    C:/OpenCV2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_highgui.a(cap_images.o): In function `CvCapture_Images::grabFrame()':
    cap_images.cpp:(.text._ZN16CvCapture_Images9grabFrameEv+0x1e): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
    C:/OpenCV2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_highgui.a(cap_ffmpeg.o): In function `CvCapture_FFMPEG_proxy::retrieveFrame(int)':
    cap_ffmpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN22CvCapture_FFMPEG_proxy13retrieveFrameEi[CvCapture_FFMPEG_proxy::retrieveFrame(int)]+0x50): undefined reference to `cvInitImageHeader'
    cap_ffmpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN22CvCapture_FFMPEG_proxy13retrieveFrameEi[CvCapture_FFMPEG_proxy::retrieveFrame(int)]+0x5a): undefined reference to `cvSetData'
    C:/OpenCV2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_highgui.a(cap_ffmpeg.o): In function `CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy::writeFrame(_IplImage const*)':
    cap_ffmpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN26CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy10writeFrameEPK9_IplImage[CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy::writeFrame(_IplImage const*)]+0x5e): undefined reference to `cv::Exception::Exception(int, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)'
    cap_ffmpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN26CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy10writeFrameEPK9_IplImage[CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy::writeFrame(_IplImage const*)]+0x64): undefined reference to `cv::error(cv::Exception const&)'
    cap_ffmpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN26CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy10writeFrameEPK9_IplImage[CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy::writeFrame(_IplImage const*)]+0x6a): undefined reference to `cv::Exception::~Exception()'
    cap_ffmpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN26CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy10writeFrameEPK9_IplImage[CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy::writeFrame(_IplImage const*)]+0x11c): undefined reference to `cv::Exception::~Exception()'
C:/OpenCV2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_tiff.o): In function `cv::TiffEncoder::newEncoder() const':
grfmt_tiff.cpp:(.text._ZNK2cv11TiffEncoder10newEncoderEv+0x16): undefined reference to `cv::fastMalloc(unsigned int)'
C:/OpenCV2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_tiff.o): In function `cv::TiffDecoder::newDecoder() const':
grfmt_tiff.cpp:(.text._ZNK2cv11TiffDecoder10newDecoderEv+0x16): undefined reference to `cv::fastMalloc(unsigned int)'
C:/OpenCV2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_tiff.o): In function `cv::TiffDecoder::~TiffDecoder()':
grfmt_tiff.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11TiffDecoderD1Ev+0x48): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
grfmt_tiff.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11TiffDecoderD1Ev+0x6e): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
        .
        .
        .
```

first I download latest version of openCV and build it and then use libs. also in

project.pro

add this lines:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\OpenCV2.3.1\include\opencv" 
LIBS +="C:/OpenCV2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_androidcamera.a" \
"C:/OpenCV2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_calib3d.a" \
"C:/OpenCV2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp.a" \ .
...
```

can necessitas support openCV? why show this errors?

sorry for my English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate OpenCV into Qt Creator Android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562311/how-to-integrate-opencv-into-qt-creator-android-project)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that **order** of the .a files matter. Put them in this order (Change the path to your paths) works for me:

```
LIBS += \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_calib3d.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_flann.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_objdetect.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_contrib.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_video.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_ml.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_legacy.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_highgui.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/liblibjpeg.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/liblibpng.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/liblibtiff.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/liblibjasper.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libzlib.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_ts.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_androidcamera.a \
    /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_features2d.a

INCLUDEPATH += /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/include/opencv/ \
               /media/Software/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/include/
```

Answer (score 0):

find and add libtiff.a, it may be in opencv 3rd party libraries directory.